# Refactoring Backgroundworker to async/await

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm

I've always used the Backgroundworker and I'm new to async/await keywords. Right now I'm trying to refactor some code from Backgroundworker to async/await (It's a WPF MVVM app).

I got a Command in my vm, which is instantiated like this:

```
GenerateCommand = new DelegateCommand(GenerateHandler, CanGenerate);
```

I've seen there is an 'AsyncCommand' in the dev express lib, which will probably work for me.

All the handler does is register an eventhandler to the finished event and call the Generate method on a service.

```
private void GenerateHandler()
{
  generatorService.GenerationFinished += OnGenerationFinished;
  generatorService.Generate(mDataFields, mGenerateFilesViewModel, mAmount);      
}
```

Then the Generate method of the service starts a BackGroundWorker:

```
public void Generate(IEnumerable<IDataField> dataFields, IGenerateFilesViewModel generateFilesViewModel, int amount)
{
  BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
  worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
  worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

The DoWork method does the time consuming task

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  GenerateCommand generateCommand = null;
  if (mUploadFiles)
  {
    generateCommand = new GenerateCommand(mDataFields, mOutputDirectory, mTemplateFileName, mAmount, mSelectedCollection, mSelectedAccountKey);
  }
  else
  {
    generateCommand = new GenerateCommand(mDataFields, mOutputDirectory, mTemplateFileName, mAmount);
  }

  try
  {
    generateCommand.Execute();
  }
  catch (SEHException ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Generation of files threw an exception. {0}", ex.Message));
  }
}
```

I'm unsure which method I have to mark with the async keyword now and where I have to await for my async method. I tryed to mark the worker_DoWork as async and  await the call in the Generate method, but then the Generate method has to be marked as async too in order to be awaitable in the GenerateHandler of the vm?

Sorry if I'm confusing you, but all this is confusing me abit...

thanks for the help

Comment: You should be able to completely migrate to async/await by rewriting the DoWork event handler to an async method and await on it somewhere in your code and then completely remove BackgroundWorker.

Comment: `GenerateHandler` and `GenerateMdfHandler` is a typo or they are a different methods?

Comment: @Sam It was a typo, sorry

Answer (score 3):

One of the async/await syntax sugar benefits is coding convenience - you can write truly asynchronous method just as such consequentially as you usually write synchronous method.

Here you have `worker_DoWork` heavy payload and `OnGenerationFinished` final method. So your `GenerateHandler` can look like this:

```
private async void GenerateHandler()
{
    await Task.Run(() => worker_DoWork());

    OnGenerationFinished();
}
```

If your `OnGenerationFinished` method logic does not directly change any UI elements, you can even more offload UI thread by using `ConfigureAwait`:

```
await Task.Run(() => worker_DoWork()).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Here I show the idea, without considering your particular `generatorService` realization. Your final realization probably will not exactly the same.

**Some notes:**

Usually *async* method should return `Task` or `Task<T>`, but as soon as `GenerateHandler` is actually a handler of the command, it is normal in that case to have a *void* return type.

How this example will work (in simple words):

After `GenerateHandler` invoked in UI thread, `Task.Run` will delegate `worker_DoWork` processing to the thread from the threadpool, so UI thread remains free for responding to UI events.

What *await* keyword do: after `Task.Run` creates task in threadpool, it just returns from `GenerateHandler`. But it remember the rest of the method (which is `OnGenerationFinished` in that case) and current synchronization context (UI thread in that case), in which the rest of the method will be processed after `worker_DoWork` will finish the work.

But if you don't need UI thread for `OnGenerationFinished` processing, you can tell *await* not to use current synchronization context for invoking the rest of the method, this is what `ConfigureAwait(false)` for. In that case `OnGenerationFinished` will be executed in another thread from threadpool, allowing UI thread not to distract for non-UI job.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good practice but it works just fine for me:

```
    void Something()
    {
     if (!mybworker.IsBusy())
     { 
      mybworker.RunWorkerAsync(); 
     }
    while (mybworker.IsBusy())
    {
     Application.DoEvents();
    }
   }
```